# Binding XAMLCropControl ImageSource to ImageSource property in ViewModel failed

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, crop, windows-10-universal

I am using the [XamlCropControl](https://xamlcropcontrol.codeplex.com/) and trying to bind its `ImageSource` property in my viewmodel.

```
    private ImageSource source;
    public ImageSource Source
    {
        get { return source; }
        set { SetProperty(ref source, value); }
    }
```

The image is picked from user's gallery as `StorageFile`

```
    private async void setImageSource()
    {
        if (ImageStorageFile != null)
        {
            var imageProperties = await ImageStorageFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)imageProperties.Width, (int)imageProperties.Height);
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await ImageStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            wb.SetSource(fileStream);
            Source = wb;
            Show();
        }
    }
```

In my XAML I have the following

```
  <xamlcrop:CropControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="cropControl" ImageSource="{Binding Source}" DesiredAspectRatio="{Binding AspectRatio, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

But the image is not showing. But if I use the path like in the sample such as

```
 <xamlcrop:CropControl x:Name="Crop" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/wrench.jpg" />
```

it works. I set a breakpoint in the `CropControl.cs` and indeed the `Writeablebitmap` was passed to the dependencyproperty but it's not shown. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you've done all things right about data binding, then according to the open source of `XamlCropControl` you provided, from your code, you've set a `WriteableBitmap` as the `Source` of the `CropControl`.

You can refer to the source code of `CropControl`, in its `Setup()` and `DoFullLayout()` methods, which are used for rendering the image source on this control, the code is like this:

```cs
public void Setup()
{
    // Check for loaded and template succesfully applied
    if (!_isLoaded ||
        !_isTemplateApplied)
    {
        return;
    }

    _image.Source = ImageSource;
    var bi = _image.Source as BitmapImage;
    if (bi != null)
    {
       ...
    }
}

 private void DoFullLayout()
 {
     if (!_isTemplateApplied)
     {
         return;
     }

     var bi = _image.Source as BitmapImage;
     if (bi == null)
     {
         return;
     }
     ...
}
```

As you can see here, it casts the source of image to `BitmapImage` using `as`, since your source is a `WriteableBitmap`, here it will fail to cast and return null. This is the first possible reason for your problem. If you insist to use `WriteableBitmap`, you will need to modify these code to change `BitmapImage` to your `WriteableBitmap`.

Another possible problem is with its `Setup` method:

```cs
var bi = _image.Source as WriteableBitmap;
if (bi != null)
{
    bi.ImageOpened += (sender, e) =>
    {
        DoFullLayout();
        if (this.ImageOpened != null)
        {
            this.ImageOpened(this, e);
        }
    };
}
```

If you pass a `BitmapImage` as the source, when I use `UriSource` to generate this `BitmapImage`, then everything goes fine. But when I use `SetSource` to set file stream to this `BitmapImage`, then the `ImageOpened` event will magically **NOT** be fired by my side, I'm not sure what happens here. But you're using `WriteableBitmap`, there is no `ImageOpend` event of `WriteableBitmap`, you will need to modify this code anyway. For example, I'm now changing it like this:

```cs
var bi = _image.Source as WriteableBitmap;
if (bi != null)
{
    //bi.ImageOpened += (sender, e) =>
    //{
    //    DoFullLayout();
    //    if (this.ImageOpened != null)
    //    {
    //        this.ImageOpened(this, e);
    //    }
    //};
    try
    {
        DoFullLayout();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Now it works and you can handle the exception by yourself.

Since you didn't mention which template did you used for UWP app development, I'm here just using standard method to deliver a demo in case you have something wrong with data binding:

MainPage xaml:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

...
<Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
    <xamlcrop:CropControl x:Name="Crop" ImageSource="{Binding Source}" DesiredAspectRatio="1.0" />
</Border>
<Button Content="Pick Image" Command="{Binding SetImageSource}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

MainPageViewModel:

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        source = null;
    }

    public ICommand SetImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommandHandler(() => this.setImageSource());
        }
    }

    public async void setImageSource()
    {
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wrench.jpg"));
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(960, 1200);
                wb.SetSource(stream);
                Source = wb;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    private ImageSource source;

    public ImageSource Source
    {
        get { return source; }
        set
        {
            if (value != source)
            {
                source = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My `CommandHandler` is simple like this:

```cs
public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private Action _action;

    public CommandHandler(Action action)
    {
        this._action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._action();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I am using Template10 but I can adjust accordingly to follow your recommendations.